# How to search Amazon S3 Bucket from Android

Tags: java, android, amazon-web-services, android-studio, amazon-s3

I want to search particular key or tags from android device. For instance i want to search for an Image, how can I do it using java code ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't recommend keeping AWS credentials on mobile device. Either you make the bucket public (if it's safe) or create a backend service to search.
For public buckets, you get deterministic url, so you can directly call the url with image name, either it will return the image or will give you an error.
In case you create a backend service (or for that matter use in android device) first create an S3 client.

```
public boolean fileExists(String fileName, String s3Bucket) {
    boolean fileExists = true;
    try {
        s3client.getObjectMetadata(s3Bucket, fileName);
    } catch (final AmazonS3Exception s3e) {
        if (s3e.getStatusCode() == 404) {
            // i.e. 404: NoSuchKey - The specified key does not exist
            fileExists = false;
        } else {
            throw s3e; // rethrow all S3 exceptions other than 404
        }
    }

    return fileExists;
}
```

Similarly, you can get the file as well.